# Чат-боти чи чатботи?

Tags: орфографія, разом-дефіс-окремо

Нещодавно прочитала цікаву статтю про [IT-технології](http://it-ua.info/news/2016/10/03/chat-boti-yak-nam-z-cim-dopomozhe-microsoft.html), де натрапила на нове для себе слово **чат-боти**. На цьому сайті це слово пишеться через дефіс, так само у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82), але на сайті [THE FUTURE](http://thefuture.news/chatbot) бачимо написання цього слова разом. Можливо, на 2-й варіант вплинуло написання [англ. chatbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatbot).

Отже, як правильно писати **чат-боти чи чатботи**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я вважаю, що має писатись через дефіс.

> [§ 26. Складні іменники](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par26)
>
> 1. **Разом пишуться**:
>      **а**) складні іменники, утворені шляхом поєднання за допомогою **сполучного звука** двох або кількох основ, одна з яких — дієслівного походження: *вертоліт*, *лісосплав*, *самохід*, *силосонавантажувач*, *тепловоз* **[не підходить]**;
>      **б**) складні іменники, утворені поєднанням **прикметникової** та іменникової основ за допомогою сполучного звука: *білокрівці*, *чорногуз*, *чорнозем* **[не підходить]**;
>      **в**) складні іменники, утворені за допомогою **сполучного звука** від двох іменникових основ: *верболіз*, *лісостеп*, *носоріг*, *трудодень*, *шлакоблок*; але *людино-день*; сюди ж належать іменники, першою частиною яких є незмінний іменник іншомовного походження (тут роль **сполучного звука** виконує останній голосний першого іменника: *автострада*, *велотрек*, *радіокомітет*) **[не підходить]**;
>      **г**) складні іменники, утворені з **дієслова в наказовій формі** та іменника: *горицвіт*, *зірвиголова*, *перекотиполе*, *пройдисвіт*; *Непийпиво*, *Перебийніс*, *Убийвовк* (прізвища) **[не підходить]**;
>      **ґ**) складні іменники, утворені з кількісного **числівника у формі родового відмінка** (для числівника сто — називного) та іменника: *дванадцятитонка*, *сторіччя*, *стоп’ятдесятиріччя*, *шестиденка* **[не підходить]**.
>      Примітка. <…>;
>      **д**) складні іменники **з першою частиною пів-, напів-, полу-**: *піваркуша*, *півгодини*, *півдюжини*, *півкарбованця*, *півколо*, *півмісяць*, *півогірка*, *пів’яблука*; *напівавтомат*, *напівсон*; *полукіпок*, *полумисок* **[не підходить]**.
>      Примітка. <…>;
>      **е**) складні іменники, утворені **з трьох і більше основ**: *автомотогурток*, *світловодолікування*, *термогідродинаміка* **[не підходить]**.
> 2. **Через дефіс пишуться:**
>      **1**) складні іменники, утворені **з двох іменників без допомоги сполучного звука**, незалежно від того, чи в даному слові відмінюються обидва іменники, чи тільки другий **[підходить]**.
>
>    - До слів з обома відмінюваними частинами належать:
>        <…>
>    - До слів із другою відмінюваною частиною належать:
>        **а**) іменники, в яких перше слово підкреслює певну прикмету чи особливість предмета, явища, названого другим словом: *блок-система*, *буй-тур*, *дизель-мотор*, *жар-птиця*, *козир-дівка*, *крекінг-процес*, *Свят-вечір*, *стоп-кран* **[зовсім підходить]**;
>        <…>;
>
>    <…>.

(Виділення напівжирним і висновки «підходить»/«не підходить» мої.)

Comment: Чому тоді "блокчейн" пишеться разом?

Comment: @Palindromer, бо в українській мові є слово «блок», але немає слова «чейн» (хоча і якби було, то все одно могло б писатися разом, бо практика може переважати теорію; до речі, є проект правопису 2018, можливо, там це по-іншому, я не дивився).